# Azure Pipelines build vs release NPM install speeds

Tags: npm, azure-pipelines

We have both build and release pipelines in classic and have exactly the same tasks. The only difference as I know of is that some fields in the release pipeline tasks needs to indicate the `$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)`. Other than that I can say they are completely identical. Our pipelines goes like this:

1. Node.js tool installer
2. npm install --legacy-peer-deps
3. npm build
4. DockerBuildandPush

My concern is that the release pipelines executes the `npm install --legacy-peer-deps` task for about 13+ mins while in our build pipelines are less than 1min. Both release and build pipelines uses the same private agent pool. I'm assuming that in the build pipelines it internally caches the npm packages and now I'm exploring the cache task in release pipeline but having permission issues.

So my problem and question: is there a way to increase the speed for the `npm install --legacy-peer-deps` task in the release pipeline? or make it execute with the same execution time as the build pipeline?

Comment: Would you please confirm: 1. Are you installing packages for the same project in the build and release pipeline? 2. There can be several agent in one agent pool. Please check whether your build and release pipeline are running on the same agent. 3. What's the artifact of your release pipeline? The build pipeline or the same repo used in build? 4. Please add the variable `system.debug` and set the value to `true` in your pipeline. Then trigger the build and release. Compare the debug logs when run npm install to see what's the difference.

Comment: 1. Yes, both pipelines builds the same artifact/repository. 2. We only have 2 agents in the agent pool and we have tested on both agents Both resulted in the same way(slow in release pipelines; fast in build pipelines). 3. We are using azure repository for the artifacts. 4. I have already did that and the only difference I can see are the release pipeline specific log entries only.

Comment: Also I would like to add. I've tested and cloned the same build pipeline to a test build pipeline and the first run was about ~15mins then the second run was <1min which is not the same on the succeeding runs in the release pipelines.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the build pipeline behavior differs from the release pipeline is that in our case the build pipeline is not cleaning up the files from the build run, meaning in the succeeding runs, it will already consists of the node_modules folder + repository files(which I assume is updated on checkout). And since the node_modules folder already exist with the modules from the previous run, the `npm install` task will only download and unpack only the new modules.

The work around we will currently do in the release pipeline is to manually store the node_modules in some place in our build agent machine and only update it when there is a new change in the package.json.

The pipeline will look like this:

1. Copy cached node_modules into pipeline directory
2. npm install
3. npm build
4. docker build and push
5. if there are changes in the package.json or node_modules in the pipeline directory, update the cached node_modules
6. profit?

P.S. as of writing the cache task is not supported in the classic release pipeline.